# javascript indexOf always returning -1

Tags: javascript, indexof

making (lame) game, and i want to check if selected square contains a monster, however my indexOf keeps returning -1. relevant code below.

intialization:

```
var monsters = [];

var monsterPositions = [2,8,13,15,22];

var player = { "currentPosition": 0 };

for ( var i in monsterPositions ) {
    monsters[i] = new createMonster("monster",monsterPositions[i],1); }

function createMonster(name,startingPoint,level) {
    this.currentPosition = startingPoint; }
```

function triggered with `<td>` onclick:

```
function processClick(trigger){
    console.log( trigger.id + " " + monsterPositions );
    if ( monsterPositions.indexOf(trigger.id) >= 0 ){
        if ( !fight( findMonster( parseInt( trigger.id ) ) ) ){
            return;
        }
    }
    if ( gameOn ) move( parseInt( trigger.id ) );
}
```

the page always goes straight to `move()`, even when  it is a monster spot, here is `console.log()` results:

```
1 2,8,13,15,22 adventure.js (line 79)
2 2,8,13,15,22 adventure.js (line 79)
7 2,8,13,15,22 adventure.js (line 79)
8 2,8,13,15,22 adventure.js (line 79)
13 2,8,13,15,22 adventure.js (line 79)
18 2,8,13,15,22 adventure.js (line 79)
23 2,8,13,15,22 adventure.js (line 79)
22 2,8,13,15,22 adventure.js (line 79)
21 2,8,13,15,22 adventure.js (line 79)
20 2,8,13,15,22 adventure.js (line 79)
15 2,8,13,15,22 adventure.js (line 79)
```

[(link here if above code isnt enough)](http://borisute.com/geshem/2013/mkeller/adventure.html), and im stumped help please.(of course why else would i be here)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`trigger.id` is probably returning a string where your array is full of numbers.

[This jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cRVjW/1/) shows that in action as well as it working with a Number and how to convert your string IDs to numbers using `parseInt()`.

Comment: oh wow i knew that just spaced, lol i had this before, (as you can see i use parseInt on the next line) thanks.

Comment: Be sure to _always_ pass 10 as the second argument of `parseInt(trigger.id,10)`

Comment: yeah whats up with that? i dont really get the whole "radix" thing.

Comment: According to MDN 
"An integer that represents the radix of the above mentioned string. Always specify this parameter to eliminate reader confusion and to guarantee predictable behavior. Different implementations produce different results when a radix is not specified." If you do `parseInt('08')` on certain browsers, you won't get 8.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 if ( monsterPositions.indexOf(Number(trigger.id)) >== 0 )
```

Comment: ive never heard of `number` before i will check it up and try it, but `parseInt` is a known valid function, i dont see why it would work.

Comment: It is bad practice to use `Number`

Comment: thanks anyway was a bit spaced didnt notice that i missed `parseInt` as you can see from my comment

Comment: @Zero21xxx Can you also add why it's bad practice? :D

Comment: Well for one reason, it can easily be overridden. Anyone in any file can simply do `Number = function() {return false}` and BAM, now your code is broken. It is generally preferred to use literal notation if possible or any of the dozen other ways to convert a string to a number.